# Fixing this error "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt"

Tags: errors

I've read the FAQs and searched the help center. 
My URL is: www.myshopzilla.com

My site description is not appearing on google search - just this error "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt"
 so please advice me what can i do .

Comment: There could be many reasons why your site is blocking entry to search engines. A good place to start looking is under the settings->read on your dashboard.

Comment: Can you view source of your website and look for `<meta name="robots"` and tell us if you can find it and what the `content="???"` value is.

Answer (score 0):

[Settings > Reading > Search Engine Visibility](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen) - make sure the option "Discourage search engines from indexing this site" is unchecked. You'll need to wait for Google to update its index.

Comment: yes this option is already unchecked.